# C# Entity Framework doesn't rollback transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to create and commit an entity. After this I do some other operation that can generate an exception. In catch I need to delete created entity and rollback any other operation.

Here is a code example:

```
try {
    // Some code to create my entity

    // Commit create operation
    DbContext.SaveChanges();
    DbContext.Database.CurrentTransaction.Commit();

    // Update an existing entity
    anotherEntity.Counter++;

    AnotherEntityType result = DbContext.Set<AnotherEntityType>().Find(anotherEntity.Id);
    DbEntityEntry<AnotherEntityType> attachedEntry = DbContext.Entry(result);

    attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(anotherEntity);
    attachedEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    
    // Some other code
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // Rollback and start new transaction
    DbContext.Database.CurrentTransaction.Rollback();
    DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();      

    // Delete already commited entity
    EntityType entity = DbContext.Set<EntityType>().Find(createdEntity.Id);
    DbSet<EntityType> dbSet = DbContext.Set<EntityType>();

    if (DbContext.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached) {
        dbSet.Attach(entity);
    }

    dbSet.Remove(entity);

    // Commit delete operation
    DbContext.SaveChanges();
    DbContext.Database.CurrentTransaction.Commit();
}
```

The problem is that my update persist and commit in catch effectively update the entity ignoring rollback.

How can I solve this problem? I tried to close and open connection but nothing change.

Comment: The only way for that catch to rollback is it's hit before the commit. The commit needs to be the very last thing that the try block does

Comment: Sorry, but this example smells a bit of not trusting EF to manage your navigation references and FKs. An operation with EF across several related entities should ideally only ever need to involve one single `SaveChanges` call, and should only involve an explicit transaction when you want to link this `SaveChanges()` with operations taken against a separate `DbContext` or other external transaction-supporting operation. (I.e. save changes and send an e-mail, if e-mail send fails, roll back saved changes.)

Comment: @StevePy I understand what you mean and I agree, but the software architecture cause that I need to obtain the entity ID for some other operation.